# How to find x-intercepts of the graph of $f$

Tags: functions

Given the following function $$f(x) =  \frac {\sin (4x)}{2x}$$

How to find $x$-intercepts of the graph of $f$ on the interval $0 \le x \le \pi$?

Answer (score 1):

For x-intercepts, $f(x)=0$

Observe that at $\displaystyle x=0,f(x)=\frac00$ i.e., undefined

So, we need $\sin4x=0,x\ne0\implies 4x=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer$\ne0$

$\implies x=\frac{n\pi}4$

Now for the given interval, $0<\frac{n\pi}4\le \pi\iff 0<n\le 4$

Comment: I'm still confused, sorry. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @Grey, sure. $x$ intercept means when $f(x)$ intersects with $x$ axis whose eqaution is $y=0$

Comment: Is it x=(πn/2) and x=1/4(2πn+π) ?

Comment: @Grey, not sure how you have found this, but observe that this is same as $x=n\frac{\pi}4$

Comment: I'm not sure either. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Grey, my pleasure. Hope you understood my method